# Google Directions API Encoded Polyline

Tags: google-maps, encoding, google-directions-api

I am trying to map routes which should match the Google Maps street network.

I know how to serialize the JSON result from the Google Maps Directions API.

I am looking now at encoding the polylines from the individual routing steps.

I have found some decoder algorithm here on stackoverflow but tested first Google's own [Interactive Polyline Encoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility). I would expect the encoded line to match the Google Map but it doesn't.

The screenshot shows the result of an encoded segment in the Interactive Polyline Encoder on the left and the result from a Google Maps route on the right.

[image]

The encoded polyline is "uxhuBxrc|QPA@?@?B?B@@B@D@HDFD@B@H@JBB@DBFJ"

Is it possible that the Algorithm in Google's Interactive Polyline Encoder is wrong?

Has anyone tested [Jeffrey Sambells algorithm](http://jeffreysambells.com/2010/05/27/decoding-polylines-from-google-maps-direction-api-with-java) and knows whether the results match the results from Google's Interactive decoder?

Cheers,
Dennis

EDIT: The problem is with the returned polyline segments and not the encoding algorithm. Even the sample segment which Google provides in the example response on the Directions API page fits very poorly with the underlying road geometry.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get a polyline from Google maps directions V3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180104/get-a-polyline-from-google-maps-directions-v3)

Comment: not a duplicate of aforementioned question. i have meanwhile run the algorithm to decode the polyline myself and the result is the same as shown in the interactive polyline encoder. the question is therefore why are the results from the directions api different from the polyline results shown in the google maps application?

Comment: because as I said in the answer (which you claim you read and isn't a duplicate) the overview_path encoded polyline is simplified.

Comment: i am not using the overview_path. i am digitizing the actual segment as in routes.legs.steps.polyline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a hard time with this as well. The only solution I managed to come up with (works great though) is to use Google's snap to road API. Send the coordinates of your inaccurate polyline to the API and it will give back the corrected coordinates.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow. Sounds cool. I stopped working with Google Maps in favour of OpenStreetMap. But I will mark this as correct answer as I believe that this will work.

Comment: I tried this and it works nicely, however, the snapping works only with points that are relatively close to each other (~300 meters). Directions api gives me points with distance between them more than few km when it is going through straight roads, and that's when Roads API breaks and gives bad snapping. Out of ideas how to counter it. I need directions API to return more points, but there is no such setting "maximum distance between steps"

Comment: @Starwave Way back when I was working with Google Maps, I wrote a quick class which handles all this for you. Look at [BVAccurateRoutePlot](https://github.com/vinczebalazs/BVAccurateRoutePlot)

Comment: I started using "OpenRoute Service" as alternative of Google Maps. It gets me the points of polyline in json format so I can use those directly in my code. Check the website: https://openrouteservice.org/dev/#/api-docs/directions/get  and check this API: https://api.openrouteservice.org/directions?api_key=YOUR_API_KEY&coordinates=-77.132087,-11.9460073%7C-71.5342979,-16.4003839&profile=driving-car&geometry_format=geojson

Answer (score 0):

After a few months I finally got a reply from Google. Unfortunately they weren't able to understand the problem and help. I looked again at the decoding algorithm and I am now able to answer the question myself.

The algorithm rounds coordinates to 1e5.

[Google Polyline algorithm](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm)

It will therefore be impossible to encode a polyline which fits with the rendering of the underlying road network which has a higher accuracy at the highest zoom level.

This image shows the maximum positional accuracy with coordinates rounded to 1e5.

[image]

Comment: Hi! Did you manage to solve this issue or find a workaround? Or you just settled for the bad looking polylines?

Comment: Never found a solution and then stopped using Google Maps altogether as we want to be 100% OpenSource / OpenData.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this: http://zevross.com/blog/2014/09/23/convert-google-directions-to-geojson-points-or-polylines/?subscribe=success#blog_subscription-3

You could try hhe following steps (if you're using Node.js):

```
npm install polyline
```

And then:

```
var polyline = require('polyline');

// returns an array of lat, lon pairs
polyline.decode('_p~iF~ps|U_ulLnnqC_mqNvxq`@')
```

Where the string "_p~iF~ps|U_ulLnnqC_mqNvxq`@" is extracted from the response of Google Maps API: root > routes > overview_polyline > points

[image]

The resulting points in a map could be shown like this:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

[image]

You can also download a sample project from

https://github.com/xomena-so/so47492459

Don't forget to replace the API key with yours.

I hope this helps!