# How we can draw a line on google map using legs points in iOS7

Tags: google-maps, polyline

I am using overview_path for polyline on google map, but it is not turning perfectly while a turn is there on the map.
[image]

so now I am trying to draw the path using leg points. Please tell me how I can store all leg points and draw a path.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get a polyline from Google maps directions V3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180104/get-a-polyline-from-google-maps-directions-v3/16180970#16180970)