# print google map route segments

Tags: google-maps, routes

Please tell me how to get a list of the last settlements in the itinerary? that's how it is done at this site 
http://ati.su/Trace/default.aspx?EntityType=Trace&City1=3611&City5=1100&WithinCountry=false

(move the site in English via Google Translate), thank you very much for your attention

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look to Google's documentation directly about [Geocoded waypoints](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#GeocodedWaypoints):

> Details about the geocoding of every waypoint, as well as origin and
>   destination, can be found in the (JSON) `geocoded_waypoints` array.
>   These can be used to infer why the service would return unexpected or
>   no routes.
>
> Elements in the `geocoded_waypoints` array correspond, by their
>   zero-based position, to the origin, the waypoints in the order they
>   are specified, and the destination. [...]

More specifically you would look into types:

> types indicates the address type of the geocoding result used for
>   calculating directions. The following types are returned:
>
> - `street_address` indicates a precise street address.
> - `route` indicates a named route (such as "US 101").
> - `intersection` indicates a major intersection, usually of two major roads. political indicates a political entity. Usually, this type
>     indicates a polygon of some civil administration.
> - `neighborhood` indicates a named neighborhood
> - `premise` indicates a named location, usually a building or collection of buildings with a common name
> - `subpremise` indicates a first-order entity below a named location, usually a singular building within a collection of buildings with a
> - `airport` indicates an airport.
> - `point_of_interest` indicates a named point of interest. Typically, these "POI"s are prominent local entities that don't easily fit in
>     another category, such as "Empire State Building" or "Statue of
>     Liberty."
> - [...]

Among other types you want to highlight.

[Legs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Legs) also may help you (if there are no waypoints):

> Each element in the legs array specifies a single leg of the journey
>   from the origin to the destination in the calculated route. For routes
>   that contain no waypoints, the route will consist of a single "leg,"
>   but for routes that define one or more waypoints, the route will
>   consist of one or more legs, corresponding to the specific legs of the
>   journey.

And each leg has a [steps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Steps) array:

> Each element in the steps array defines a single step of the
>   calculated directions. A step is the most atomic unit of a direction's
>   route, containing a single step describing a specific, single
>   instruction on the journey. E.g. "Turn left at W. 4th St." The step
>   not only describes the instruction but also contains distance and
>   duration information relating to how this step relates to the
>   following step. For example, a step denoted as "Merge onto I-80 West"
>   may contain a duration of "37 miles" and "40 minutes," indicating that
>   the next step is 37 miles/40 minutes from this step.

Where each step has:

> - `start_location` contains the location of the starting point of this
>     step, as a single set of lat and lng fields.
> - `end_location` contains the
>     location of the last point of this step, as a single set of lat and
>     lng fields.

Comment: Thank you my friend ,but i don't know English ,can you take me the example ? i already ,but I tried, but got a completely different information.I probably used a different method

Comment: @გიორგიდარბაიძე Ok, just take a look at [this legs example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16180970/1326147). Once you have those legs you can do like this: `route.legs[i].start_address` to obtain the locations, you can generate the list by looping all the legs: inspect the script (press F12) in the [example itself](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_directions_custom_iconsC.html) and search for legs :)

Comment: Thank you for attention ...
This script will display very detailed information, the streets, and I only want the settlements there, see the link to the description, see how it is done, I want to show the towns and other populated objects.

Comment: @გიორგიდარბაიძე Then look directly into the page you provided [maps JS file - ATIMap.js](http://ati.su/js/ATIMap.js). It's readable and from there you can adapt their things.