# Google Map API Failed on Marker Click - Default Polyline Disappears - JS

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, geolocation

I'm combining Google Map API Directions and Places together and my target is :

1.Geolocate my position;

2.Search nearby places, "sushi" in my codes below;

3.Create markers on the map;

4(1).Everytime when I click one marker, the critical information of the marker displays on the left sidebar;

4(2).And there's a default blue polyline showing the route between my position and the clicked marker;

5.The route refreshes itself upon the next click.

However, my problem is that the default blue polyline couldn't show in the map that I made. I checked the console and there are no errors and Direction API **can** get a response from my code. The response even includes the code of the default blue polyline but somehow it disappears from the map.
[Response from Google Map Direction API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmChe.jpg)

I've also posted my codes on GitHub and thank you to all the people who show interest in my question!!

https://github.com/Sam5208/Self-study/blob/4bc218d4a3625b3e9dfc5eea1726455353a1f648/test-nearby.html

References:

1.https://github.com/googlecodelabs/google-maps-nearby-search-js/blob/master/step4/index.html
2.[Google map driving direction source code for their example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896871/google-map-driving-direction-source-code-for-their-example)
3.[JS - Google Maps API - Directions on Marker Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42111106/js-google-maps-api-directions-on-marker-click)

```
let pos;
let map;
let bounds;
let infoWindow;
let currentInfoWindow;
let service;
let infoPane;
function initMap() {
  // Initialize variables
  directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    map: map
  });
  bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
  currentInfoWindow = infoWindow;
  /* TODO: Step 4A3: Add a generic sidebar */
  infoPane = document.getElementById('panel');

  // Try HTML5 geolocation
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
      pos = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: pos,
        zoom: 15
      });
      bounds.extend(pos);

      infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
      infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
      infoWindow.open(map);
      map.setCenter(pos);

      // Call Places Nearby Search on user's location
      getNearbyPlaces(pos);
    }, () => {
      // Browser supports geolocation, but user has denied permission
      handleLocationError(true, infoWindow);
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support geolocation
    handleLocationError(false, infoWindow);
  }
}

// Handle a geolocation error
function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow) {
  // Set default location to Sydney, Australia
  pos = { lat: -33.856, lng: 151.215 };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: pos,
    zoom: 15
  });

  // Display an InfoWindow at the map center
  infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
  infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
    'Geolocation permissions denied. Using default location.' :
    'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
  infoWindow.open(map);
  currentInfoWindow = infoWindow;

  // Call Places Nearby Search on the default location
  getNearbyPlaces(pos);
}

// Perform a Places Nearby Search Request
function getNearbyPlaces(position) {
  let request = {
    location: position,
    rankBy: google.maps.places.RankBy.DISTANCE,
    keyword: 'sushi'
  };

  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch(request, nearbyCallback);
}

// Handle the results (up to 20) of the Nearby Search
function nearbyCallback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    createMarkers(results);
  }
}

// Set markers at the location of each place result
function createMarkers(places) {
  places.forEach(place => {
    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: place.geometry.location,
      map: map,
      title: place.name
    });

    /* TODO: Step 4B: Add click listeners to the markers */
    // Add click listener to each marker
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', () => {
        clicked = marker.getPosition();
      let request = {
        placeId: place.place_id,
        fields: ['name', 'formatted_address', 'geometry', 'rating',
          'website', 'photos']
      };
      
      
      calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pos, clicked);
      console.log(clicked);

      /* Only fetch the details of a place when the user clicks on a marker.
       * If we fetch the details for all place results as soon as we get
       * the search response, we will hit API rate limits. */
      service.getDetails(request, (placeResult, status) => {
        showDetails(placeResult, marker, status)
      });
    });

    // Adjust the map bounds to include the location of this marker
    bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
  });
  /* Once all the markers have been placed, adjust the bounds of the map to
   * show all the markers within the visible area. */
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}


function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pos, clicked) {
  directionsService.route({
    origin: pos,
    destination: clicked,
    avoidTolls: true,
    avoidHighways: false,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING
  }, function(response, status) {
      console.log(response, status);
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}

/* TODO: Step 4C: Show place details in an info window */
// Builds an InfoWindow to display details above the marker
function showDetails(placeResult, marker, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    let placeInfowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    let rating = "None";
    if (placeResult.rating) rating = placeResult.rating;
    placeInfowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + placeResult.name +
      '</strong><br>' + 'Rating: ' + rating + '</div>');
    placeInfowindow.open(marker.map, marker);
    currentInfoWindow.close();
    currentInfoWindow = placeInfowindow;
    showPanel(placeResult);
  } else {
    console.log('showDetails failed: ' + status);
  }
}

/* TODO: Step 4D: Load place details in a sidebar */
// Displays place details in a sidebar
function showPanel(placeResult) {
  // If infoPane is already open, close it
  if (infoPane.classList.contains("open")) {
    infoPane.classList.remove("open");
  }

  // Clear the previous details
  while (infoPane.lastChild) {
    infoPane.removeChild(infoPane.lastChild);
  }

  /* TODO: Step 4E: Display a Place Photo with the Place Details */
  // Add the primary photo, if there is one
  if (placeResult.photos) {
    let firstPhoto = placeResult.photos[0];
    let photo = document.createElement('img');
    photo.classList.add('hero');
    photo.src = firstPhoto.getUrl();
    infoPane.appendChild(photo);
  }

  // Add place details with text formatting
  let name = document.createElement('h1');
  name.classList.add('place');
  name.textContent = placeResult.name;
  infoPane.appendChild(name);
  if (placeResult.rating) {
    let rating = document.createElement('p');
    rating.classList.add('details');
    rating.textContent = `Rating: ${placeResult.rating} \u272e`;
    infoPane.appendChild(rating);
  }
  let address = document.createElement('p');
  address.classList.add('details');
  address.textContent = placeResult.formatted_address;
  infoPane.appendChild(address);
  if (placeResult.website) {
    let websitePara = document.createElement('p');
    let websiteLink = document.createElement('a');
    let websiteUrl = document.createTextNode(placeResult.website);
    websiteLink.appendChild(websiteUrl);
    websiteLink.title = placeResult.website;
    websiteLink.href = placeResult.website;
    websitePara.appendChild(websiteLink);
    infoPane.appendChild(websitePara);
  }

  // Open the infoPane
  infoPane.classList.add("open");
}
```

Comment: See [ask].  Provide a [mcve] in the question itself, not (only) on an external site (like github).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting the `map` property of the `directionsService`.

```
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
```

Needs to be done in two places (after you create the map):

1. the nominal case (where the geolocation works)
2. the off-nominal case (where the geolocation fails)

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/5uf18qn9/)

[image: screenshot of map with a route displayed]

**code snippet:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Sushi Finder</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
     * element that contains the map. */
    #map {
      height: 100%;
      background-color: grey;
    }

    /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    /* TODO: Step 4A1: Make a generic sidebar */
    /* Styling for an info pane that slides out from the left. 
     * Hidden by default. */
    #panel {
      height: 100%;
      width: null;
      background-color: white;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 1;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      transition: all .2s ease-out;
    }

    .open {
      width: 250px;
    }

    /* Styling for place details */
    .hero {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      max-height: 166px;
      display: block;
    }

    .place,
    p {
      font-family: 'open sans', arial, sans-serif;
      padding-left: 18px;
      padding-right: 18px;
    }

    .details {
      color: darkslategrey;
    }

    a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: cadetblue;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- TODO: Step 4A2: Add a generic sidebar -->
  <!-- The slide-out panel for showing place details -->
  <div id="panel"></div>

  <!-- Map appears here -->
  <div id="map"></div>

  <script>
    /* Note: This example requires that you consent to location sharing when
     * prompted by your browser. If you see the error "Geolocation permission
     * denied.", it means you probably did not give permission for the browser * to locate you. */
    let pos;
    let map;
    let bounds;
    let infoWindow;
    let currentInfoWindow;
    let service;
    let infoPane;
    function initMap() {
      // Initialize variables
      directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
      directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        map: map
      });
      bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
      currentInfoWindow = infoWindow;
      /* TODO: Step 4A3: Add a generic sidebar */
      infoPane = document.getElementById('panel');

      // Try HTML5 geolocation
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
          pos = {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude
          };
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: pos,
            zoom: 15
          });
          directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
          bounds.extend(pos);

          infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
          infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
          infoWindow.open(map);
          map.setCenter(pos);

          // Call Places Nearby Search on user's location
          getNearbyPlaces(pos);
        }, () => {
          // Browser supports geolocation, but user has denied permission
          handleLocationError(true, infoWindow);
        });
      } else {
        // Browser doesn't support geolocation
        handleLocationError(false, infoWindow);
      }
    }

    // Handle a geolocation error
    function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow) {
      // Set default location to Sydney, Australia
      pos = { lat: -33.856, lng: 151.215 };
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: pos,
        zoom: 15
      });
      directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
      // Display an InfoWindow at the map center
      infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
      infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
        'Geolocation permissions denied. Using default location.' :
        'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
      infoWindow.open(map);
      currentInfoWindow = infoWindow;

      // Call Places Nearby Search on the default location
      getNearbyPlaces(pos);
    }

    // Perform a Places Nearby Search Request
    function getNearbyPlaces(position) {
      let request = {
        location: position,
        rankBy: google.maps.places.RankBy.DISTANCE,
        keyword: 'sushi'
      };

      service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
      service.nearbySearch(request, nearbyCallback);
    }

    // Handle the results (up to 20) of the Nearby Search
    function nearbyCallback(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        createMarkers(results);
      }
    }

    // Set markers at the location of each place result
    function createMarkers(places) {
      places.forEach(place => {
        let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: place.geometry.location,
          map: map,
          title: place.name
        });

        /* TODO: Step 4B: Add click listeners to the markers */
        // Add click listener to each marker
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', () => {
            clicked = marker.getPosition();
          let request = {
            placeId: place.place_id,
            fields: ['name', 'formatted_address', 'geometry', 'rating',
              'website', 'photos']
          };
          
              console.log("marker "+clicked.toUrlValue(6)+" clicked")
          calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pos, clicked);
          console.log(clicked);

          /* Only fetch the details of a place when the user clicks on a marker.
           * If we fetch the details for all place results as soon as we get
           * the search response, we will hit API rate limits. */
          service.getDetails(request, (placeResult, status) => {
            showDetails(placeResult, marker, status)
          });
        });

        // Adjust the map bounds to include the location of this marker
        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
      });
      /* Once all the markers have been placed, adjust the bounds of the map to
       * show all the markers within the visible area. */
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
    
    
    function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pos, clicked) {
      directionsService.route({
        origin: pos,
        destination: clicked,
        avoidTolls: true,
        avoidHighways: false,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING
      }, function(response, status) {
          console.log(response, status);
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        console.log("directionsDisplay.getMap="+directionsDisplay.getMap());
          directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        } else {
          window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
        }
      });
    }

    /* TODO: Step 4C: Show place details in an info window */
    // Builds an InfoWindow to display details above the marker
    function showDetails(placeResult, marker, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        let placeInfowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        let rating = "None";
        if (placeResult.rating) rating = placeResult.rating;
        placeInfowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + placeResult.name +
          '</strong><br>' + 'Rating: ' + rating + '</div>');
        placeInfowindow.open(marker.map, marker);
        currentInfoWindow.close();
        currentInfoWindow = placeInfowindow;
        showPanel(placeResult);
      } else {
        console.log('showDetails failed: ' + status);
      }
    }

    /* TODO: Step 4D: Load place details in a sidebar */
    // Displays place details in a sidebar
    function showPanel(placeResult) {
      // If infoPane is already open, close it
      if (infoPane.classList.contains("open")) {
        infoPane.classList.remove("open");
      }

      // Clear the previous details
      while (infoPane.lastChild) {
        infoPane.removeChild(infoPane.lastChild);
      }

      /* TODO: Step 4E: Display a Place Photo with the Place Details */
      // Add the primary photo, if there is one
      if (placeResult.photos) {
        let firstPhoto = placeResult.photos[0];
        let photo = document.createElement('img');
        photo.classList.add('hero');
        photo.src = firstPhoto.getUrl();
        infoPane.appendChild(photo);
      }

      // Add place details with text formatting
      let name = document.createElement('h1');
      name.classList.add('place');
      name.textContent = placeResult.name;
      infoPane.appendChild(name);
      if (placeResult.rating) {
        let rating = document.createElement('p');
        rating.classList.add('details');
        rating.textContent = `Rating: ${placeResult.rating} \u272e`;
        infoPane.appendChild(rating);
      }
      let address = document.createElement('p');
      address.classList.add('details');
      address.textContent = placeResult.formatted_address;
      infoPane.appendChild(address);
      if (placeResult.website) {
        let websitePara = document.createElement('p');
        let websiteLink = document.createElement('a');
        let websiteUrl = document.createTextNode(placeResult.website);
        websiteLink.appendChild(websiteUrl);
        websiteLink.title = placeResult.website;
        websiteLink.href = placeResult.website;
        websitePara.appendChild(websiteLink);
        infoPane.appendChild(websitePara);
      }

      // Open the infoPane
      infoPane.classList.add("open");
    }
  </script>

  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places&callback=initMap">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```